# Game in which the stars are right

Tags: call-of-cthulhu, product-identification, cthulhu-mythos

I recall reading the introduction fiction to an RPG years ago, and I'd like to know its name. The game was set on a Mars colony, just barely self-sufficient or possibly slowly dying off. Shortly before the stars came right and Cthulhu rose up from the oceans, and humanity went mad, dying off in an orgy of violence, at least, those on earth. The people on Mars aren't doing well, what with watching the entire rest of the human race die, and the stress of turning their temporary settlement into a permanent one, a lot go mad.

They also find ruins from a previous civilization there, that are all slightly...wrong. Also they find something stalking them, and people start going missing.

I would love to know what this was. A setting for Call of Cthulhu? A roleplaying game? I think someone mentioned it to me once that it might have been a leak or preview from a cancelled RPG, that was tossed when the publisher found it too dark for their product line.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You may be thinking of [End Time](http://www.scribd.com/doc/42511268/Call-of-Cthulhu-End-Time-Rulebook-Collected), a Call of Cthulhu supplement.

> In 1993 Pagan Publishing's End Time product came to an unceremonious end.Contained herein is the material I wrote for the project. While the project was never completed, you will find here the results of many hours of work.
>
> The End Time grew out of my Blood Moon adventure, published in Chaosium's Strange Aeons. Essentially, it is a dark future in which the stars have become right (or nearlyright) and humanity has been forced to flee the earth.

The first few pages seem to describe what you're talking about: the earth dying after freeing Domagg T'eel, a colony on Mars struggles to survive, and so on.

Comment: Holy cow, what was fast. That is exactly what I remember. Thank you.